# Functional inequality $f(x+y)f(x-y)\leq f^2(x)-f^2(y)$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, functions, contest-math, functional-equations, functional-inequalities

> Let $f:\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}$ be $$f(x+y)f(x-y)\leq f^2(x)-f^2(y)\quad \forall x,y\in\mathbb{R}.$$
>   Then prove that $$f(x)=-f(-x)$$ and $$f(x+y)f(x-y)=f^2(x)-f^2(y),$$ where $f^2(x)=\big(f(x)\big)^2$.

**Source:** KMO $1987$

The first is easy. Let the given assertion be $P(x,y)$
$$P(0,0)\implies f^2(0)\leq 0\implies f(0)=0$$
$$P(x,-x)\implies f^2(x)-f^2(-x)\geq 0\tag{*}$$
$$P(0,x)\implies -f^2(x)-f(x)f(-x)\geq 0\tag{**}$$
$$(*)+2(**)\implies -(f(x)+f(-x))^2\geq 0\implies f(x)=-f(-x)$$
But second is not easy. I'm trying to prove $f(x+y)f(x-y)\geq f^2(x)-f^2(y)$. Can anyone help me?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

\begin{align*}
f(x + y)f(x - y) &= -f(y + x)f(y - x) \\
&\geq -(f^2(y) - f^2(x)) \\
&= f^2(x) - f^2(y)
\end{align*}

Comment: Thank you for nice solution!